# How to have common components with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

So im trying to build a SPA (single page application) and i'm a little bit stumped as to how to include a common navbar through out the app without it being included through the whole application.

The way ive designed my code now is as follows:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

this is where i use browserouter at the root element.

and then i have in my App component:

```
<div>
    <Header />
    <Router>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Post} />
      {this.props.categories && this.props.categories.map((cat, i) => {
        console.log(cat.path)
        return <Route path={`/${cat.path}`} component={array[i]} key={i} />
      })}
    </Router>
  </div>
```

can someone point out what im doing wrong and how i should do it please as i havent a clue.

Answer (score 0):

in your App component use `Switch` instead of `Router` ,
You are using two routers
you can give a route for App in Browser Router

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><BrowserRouter><Route path="/" component={App} /></BrowserRouter></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In React Router V4 you are encouraged to use a top-level BrowserRouter component simply to provide the history API as context. You can actually render multiple routes simultaneously at different places in your app if you like. Try using `<Switch>` and place your routes inside of that. This component will show the first of its children that are of type `<Route>` that match the current path. Also provide the `exact` prop to make sure that nested routes don't get displayed when a deeper nesting is available. Your final example could look something like this:

```
<div>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
        {categories.map(cat => <Route {...cat} />)}
    </Switch>
</div>
```

And inside your `categories` you could have the props necessary for rendering the route, like `path` and `component`. This makes your example more concise.

```js
const Component = React.Component
const { Switch, Route, Link } = ReactRouterDOM
const Router = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter

const Home = () => <h1>Home</h1>
const Post1 = () => <h1>React</h1>
const Post2 = () => <h1>Redux</h1>
const Post3 = () => <h1>Udacity</h1>

const routes = [
 {
   name: 'Home',
   path: '/',
    component: Home
  },
  {
   name: 'React',
    path: '/react',
    component: Post1
  },
  {
   name: 'Redux',
   path: '/redux',
    component: Post2
  },
  {
   name: 'Udacity',
   path: '/udacity',
    component: Post3
  }
]

const Header = () => <header>
  <nav>
    {routes.map(route => <Link to={route.path} key={route.path} >{route.name}</Link>)}
  </nav>
</header>

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          {routes.map(route => <Route {...route} key={route.path} exact/>)}
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Router><App/></Router>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@4.2.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- NOTE: in this embedded fiddle, React Router will not work. See https://jsfiddle.net/tay99xu0/ for working demo reference. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, i replaced router with switch and it still didnt work. Im just trying to see what else it could be

Comment: Define what you mean by "It doesn't work". Do you get an error message? Does your desired route not render?

Comment: This is the file that im having trouble with https://github.com/strahinjaajvaz/react-nano-project-2/blob/master/frontend/src/components/App.js i cant seem to update the view depending on the url

Comment: I've refactored the example you gave me and saved it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tay99xu0/ so you'll see it in action. In your example in all cases the first matching path will be `/` due to the first one (Home) having a matching partial. To fix that, use the `exact` prop like I stated in my answer and also in the fiddle.